# from_json returns null in Apache Spark 3.0

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

I have a pyspark column of type string containing a array of dictionary.

```
     x = {"a":1,"b":[{"type":"abc","unitValue":"4.4"}]}
```

I want to cast the string into array of struct but while doing that the fields in the new column are getting populated as null.

Databricks run time - 8.3 (includes Apache Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12)

My dataframe looks like:

```
     from pyspark.sql.functions import *
     from pyspark.sql.types import *

     inputSchema = StructType([StructField("a",StringType(),True),
                         StructField("b",StringType(),True)])

     jsonStruct = StructType([StructField("type",StringType(),True),
                         StructField("unitValue",StringType(),True)])
     
     df = spark.createDataFrame(data =[x],schema = inputSchema).show()

     +---+---------------------------+
     |  a|                   b       |
     +---+---------------------------+
     |  1|[{type=abc, unitValue=4.4}]|
     +---+---------------------------+

     df.printSchema()
     root
     |-- a: string (nullable = true)
     |-- b: string (nullable = true)
```

I am using from_json function to achieve the same but the values are getting populated as null

```
     df1 = df.withColumn("newvalue",from_json(col("b"),jsonStruct,{"mode" : "PERMISSIVE"}))
     display(df1)
     
     +---+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
     |  a|                   b        |    newvalue                      |
     +---+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
     |  1|[{type=abc, unitValue=xyz}] |{"type": null, "unitValue": null} |
     +---+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Can someone please help me here

Answer (score 1):

In column `b` JSON structure is not proper. After creating dataframe `:` is getting replaced by `=`.

Either you have to make type of `b` as string while declaring variable itself or you have to replace `=` by `:` using [regexp_replace()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#regexp_replace)

```
x = {"a":1,"b":'[{"type":"abc","unitValue":"4.4"}]'}
```

And and you need to change JSON schema as shown below.

```
jsonStruct = ArrayType(StructType([
       StructField("type",StringType(),True), 
       StructField("unitValue",StringType(),True)]),True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is specific to spark 3.0.0 and above.
Databricks Link to issue : https://kb.databricks.com/scala/from-json-null-spark3.html
I have found the resolution as well.

```
     inputSchema = StructType([StructField("a",StringType(),True),StructField("b",StringType(),True)])

     jsonStruct = ArrayType(StructType([StructField("type",StringType(),True),StructField("unitValue",StringType(),True)]),True)

     x = {"a":1,"b":'[{"type":"abc","unitValue":"xyz"}]'}

     df = spark.createDataFrame(data =[x],schema = schema)

     df = df.withColumn("b",regexp_replace('b', '=', ':').cast(StringType()))

     df1 = df.withColumn("newvalue",from_json(col("b"),jsonStruct,{"mode" : "PERMISSIVE"}))

     display(df1)

     +---+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
     |  a|                   b        |    newvalue                      |
     +---+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
     |  1|[{type=abc, unitValue=xyz}] |{"type": "abc", "unitValue": "xyz"} |
     +---+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
```